# How to run a job with optional job Parameter in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-batch

I am passing a job parameter from curl command of my job, I am able to get the `job parameter` passed, but something weird is happing when I am not passing any `job parameter`.

I am accessing the job parameter like that

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public PaymentEntriesVerificationJob paymentEntriesVerificationJob(@Value("#{jobParameters[params] ?: 1}") String params){
    PaymentEntriesVerificationJob paymentEntriesVerificationJob = new PaymentEntriesVerificationJob();
    paymentEntriesVerificationJob.setParams(params);
    return paymentEntriesVerificationJob;
}
```

So according to code, if no jobParameters params were send  `String params` will be set as 1.
but whenever I don't send any `jobParameters`, params are set as the previous job parameter value.
i.e,

```
case 1) jobcall -d 'jobParameters=bufferTime=4'
    params = 4

case 2) jobcall  (without any jobParameters)
   params = 4

case 3) jobcall -d 'jobParameters=bufferTime=5'
  params = 5
```

Why I am not able to get 1 as default value when I don't pass any job parameters

Comment: Do you have a job parameters incrementer defined in your job?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine , No but what I observed is that, it store that job parameters once it is passed caches every time in an array

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine what role does job parameters incrementer  play here?

Comment: There are two things: 1) the syntax of your spel expression is incorrect, it should be something like #{jobParameters['params']: 1}. 2) The job launcher will take parameters from the previous run and append any new parameters if any